# Modification needed in calculation of 'day' parameter in day_of_year function, to get the correct results

Tags: python-3.x, function, validation

The mentioned below script provides accurate results for calculating current day of the year, except one flaw.. which is the validation of 'day' parameter in day_of_year(year,month,day) function. Can someone please modify the code so that it should give an error/false if we, under day parameter, input value less than 0 or greater than that month's day-span.

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    if year%100==0:
        return year%400==0
    return year%4==0

def days_in_month(year, month):
    leap = is_year_leap(year)
    days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    if year<1 or month<1 or month>12: return False
    m_days = days[month-1]
    if month==2 and leap:
        m_days = 29
    return m_days

def day_of_year(year, month, day):
    total_days = 0
    for month_count in range(1,month):
        m_days1 = days_in_month(year,month_count)
        if m_days1 == None: return None
        total_days += m_days1
    total_days += day
    return total_days
    

print(day_of_year(2000, 12, 311))
print(day_of_year(2016, 6, -23))
print(day_of_year(2022,4,9))
```

Comment: Realistically, you should use python's `datetime` module for this purpose. I understand if you're doing this exercise for the sake of practise, but if you're trying to make a functional application, the `datetime` module should be your go-to for this

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return year % 400 == 0
    return year % 4 == 0


def days_in_month(year, month):
    leap = is_year_leap(year)
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if year < 1 or month < 1 or month > 12: return False
    m_days = days[month - 1]
    if month == 2 and leap:
        m_days = 29
    return m_days


def day_of_year(year, month, day):
    if not (1 <= day <= days_in_month(year, month)):
        raise ValueError

    total_days = 0
    for month_count in range(1, month):
        m_days1 = days_in_month(year, month_count)
        if m_days1 == None: return None
        total_days += m_days1
    total_days += day
    return total_days


tests = [(2000, 12, 311), (2016, 6, -23), (2022, 4, 9)]

for test in tests:
    try:
        print(day_of_year(*test))
    except ValueError as error:
        print("Day number outside allowed range.")
```